# i want to add a row in listview.builder but it goes blank

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

i want to add a row ( list of buttons that do filter the list), i tried wrapping listTile in column, listview.builde in column but it doesn't work. tried wrapping GetBuilder also but it doesn't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV14G.png)
My Code :-

```
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:get/get.dart';
        import 'package:quizzy/data_controller.dart';
        import '../models/showQuestion.dart';
    
class AllQuestionBank extends StatefulWidget {
  const AllQuestionBank({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AllQuestionBank> createState() => _AllQuestionBankState();
}

class _AllQuestionBankState extends State<AllQuestionBank> {
  final DataController controller = Get.put(DataController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      controller.getQuestionList();
    });
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(' Question Bank'),
      ),
      body: GetBuilder<DataController>(
        builder: (controller) => controller.QuestionList.isEmpty
            ? const Center(
                child: Text(' NO DATA FOUND (: '),
              )
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: controller.QuestionList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: showQuestion(controller.QuestionList[index]),
                  );
                }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know, this is you want. If you are using Inside column, try ListView.builder(shrinkWrap: true

Comment: Please share the code you are using to insert the row. Additionally: when using getx, a StatefulWidget this is usually not needed.

Comment: Worked ! .. shrinkwrap:true , 
thanks Mahi

Comment: Avoid using `shrinkwrap:true` whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could redefine your ListView as:

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: controller.QuestionList.length + 1,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (index == 0) {
        return WhateverRowYouWant();
      }
      return ListTile(
        title: showQuestion(controller.QuestionList[index - 1]),
      );
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just define the `scroll direction` to be `horizontal`.

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: controller.QuestionList.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, <- added this line
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: showQuestion(controller.QuestionList[index]),
                  );
                }),
```

You can also find an example from the official docs [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/horizontal-list)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), shrinkWrap: true,`

Answer (score 0):

To add `Row()` on top you need `Column()` widget for sure

After that, you have to wrap `ListView.builder()` with the `Expanded()` widget this will help you

Ex.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Filter'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: GetBuilder<DataController>(
            builder: (controller) => controller.QuestionList.isEmpty
                ? const Center(
                    child: Text(' NO DATA FOUND (: '),
                  )
                : ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: controller.QuestionList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: showQuestion(controller.QuestionList[index]),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Please, try this!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the combination of GetxController and ListView with a top row I use:

```dart
class MyController extends GetxController {
  var isRunning = true.obs; // set to isRunning.value = false; if done loading QuestionList 
  RxList<ProductModel> QuestionList = <ProductModel>[].obs;
}
```

```dart
Obx( () => controller.isRunning.isTrue
       ? 'Loading'
       : ListView.builder(
         itemCount: controller.QuestionList.length + 1,
         itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
           if (index == 0) {
             return Text('TOP ROW');
           }
          
           return ListTile(
              title: showQuestion(controller.QuestionList[index - 1]),
           );
                  
         }),
);
```